# Graph w Dates on x-axis

Tags: vba, excel, graph

I have a code set to self-update the x axis based on cell values. I want these values to show up as dates, but with a standard text type of formatting (for example, I have the style month-year, January-16, as each point on my x axis). But, because the user is typing in the min and max value they want into these cells referenced in the code, I want it to only be picked up as text so that this code can recognize it and plot it. I am getting an error at the line marked with ** below. I am not sure what to do. Thanks!

```
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").chart
    Select Case Target.Address
      Case "$L$37"
        **.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = Target.Value**
      Case "$L$38"
        .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = Target.Value
      Case "$L$39"
        .Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = Target.Value
      Case "$O$37"
        .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Target.Value
      Case "$O$38"
        .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Target.Value
      Case "$O$39"
        .Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = Target.Value
    End Select
  End With
```

Comment: Is the `With` statement correct? I know you can do `...ChartObjects(1).Chart`, but am not sure about using the chart name.  Try doing `With ActiveSheet.Charts("Chart 2").Chart`.

Comment: That with statement has worked thus far with me on another graph, I will try your idea

Comment: @BruceWayne , it did not work

Comment: Sorry - actually, try doing `With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2")` and leave off `.chart`.

Comment: @BruceWayne unfortunately that didnt work either. The error says "Object doesnt support this property or method." the same line is highlighted

Comment: Are you positive that the `ActiveSheet` has a chartobject named "Chart 2"?

Comment: Yes, it is named Chart 2

Answer (score 1):

Modified code, currenty I just made all the cells address manually, just to make sure the chart is being updated, and it does.

```
Public Sub Update_Chart()

With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart
    .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = Range("$L$37")
    .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = Range("$L$38")
    .Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = Range("$L$39")

    ' this line you can modifty to whatever format you want your axis to have, the user doesn't need to keep the format on the worksheet cell itself
    .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "mmm-yy" '  "[$-409]d-mmm-yy;@"

    .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("$O$37")
    .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("$O$38")
    .Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = Range("$O$39")

     ' change to whatever format you want your Y-Axis you want
    .Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "mmm-yy"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This code is in the worksheet's code, its not a Macro. Also, when I run this, I get an error under the first Case. The user is typing the dates as text into specific cells, and these cells in the code simply equal those cells that the user types in. I used this method for another graph but without a date-style x-axis and it worked

Comment: @JustinAnderson sorry, I don't seem to follow your needs. I have a code similar to this on a situation where I'm updating a chart's X-Axis,Y-Axis, and all the Series Collections according to whatever is being typed in a range of cells. I do have a trigerred event (by button, or userform), once the user finished updating the relevant chart's range, that I am running my code.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to do! The user is typing the dates into these cells and then clicking a button to update the axis.

Comment: @JustinAnderson so are you actually in the need to go through the entire range of cells here and collect your Chart data ? if so, the `Selece Case` code need some modifications...

Comment: I just need to go through the starting date they typed in, the ending date they typed in into another cell, then set the correct interval so that the axis starts and ends with those dates, and increments by month

Comment: @JustinAnderson did you try the modified code i edited in my answer ?

Comment: I am having trouble setting intervals with months. The tick for the x axis needs to be every month, and making the interval 30 is not working (cell L39 value)

Comment: @JustinAnderson are you getting an error ? what interval are you getting ? Because I am getting "Jun-16", "Jul-16" , "Aug-16", etc. what format exactly you want to get at the x-axis ?

Comment: I am getting very random numbers, from years that aren't even within range. I don't know how to get the nice even months in the range the user specifies. I will try again when I am back tomorrow and fire it up again.